# Test for NULLs in multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select columns from a table where the values of columns are NULL.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 IS NULL;
```

the above query returns rows where column1 doesn't have any value.

But I want to return multiple columns(where column1,column2,....)

I want to use this in MYSQL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE coalesce(column1, column2, column3) IS NULL;
```

You will have to enumerate all required columns. (I should confess this is a hack and should not be used in production code)

*UPD*

IF you want to check if at least a single column is null you should use OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE column1 IS NULL or column2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: @gbn, please provide an example where the check if the result of `coalesce` is null may fail.

Comment: And this assumes all columns have the same or compatible datatypes... but onlyl works for MySQL because it has loose implicit conversion rules

Comment: @gbn, nice comment. I have not known that `COALESCE` and `IFNULL` may fail on incompatible datatypes, for example, in T-SQL. Anyway, I should confess, that the solution smells and can be used only as a short hack in mysql console.

Comment: @newtover: As I said (on update) the rules for MySQL are looser and less predicatable than other RDBMS. I can't generate an error but I wouldn't rely on thie behaviour being portable http://www.ispirer.com/doc/sqlways/Output/SQLWays-1-084.html

Comment: @gbn, something like `COALESCE('qweqwe', 10)` should throw an error.

Comment: @newtover: On SQL Server, Sybase it would. ANSI 92 is vague: See `Scalar expressions   141` in http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Answer (score 3):

There is no fancy way: you have to test all columns

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE
column1 IS NULL AND
column2 IS NULL AND
...
columnn IS NULL;
```

Comment: i don't want to give IS NULL for every columnname

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **SELECT CONCAT(Column1,Column2)**

or for Variables **SELECT CONCAT(@Var1,@Var2)**:

If there is even 1 **NULL** the result will be **NULL**

```
Set @var1 = 'a',
    @var2= NULL;
SET @AnyNullValue = (SELECT CONCAT(@Var1,@Var2));
SELECT IF(@AnyNullValue IS NULL , 'YES', 'NO'); //YES

IF(@AnyNullValue IS NULL) THEN 
--your code-- ;
END IF;
```