# MySQL Select all items IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

I have the following structure:

```
//extra

item1   item2   item3
1       2       null
```

With this query I will get everything:

```
SELECT * FROM extra;
```

I would however like to only return results that don't have null and I don't want to manually type each field as these could be added at any time:

```
SELECT * FROM extra e WHERE e.sid = s.id AND * IS NOT NULL
```

This fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test for NULLs in multiple columns in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644756/test-for-nulls-in-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont know the names of columns . then you have to do this

```
  SHOW COLUMNS FROM extra
```

you can use php array of the columns you got from result .
and then you can concat your columns :

```
   WHERE CONCAT(<your list of columns>) is NOT NULL
```

Concat here returns NULL if any of the arguments are NULL.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, really though I want to return all the values that are not null, not stop the query if any are null you see. I do believe I will have to just get the query then rebuild the array with PHP